# Non invertibility of certain integral arising from group action

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, group-actions

**Edit 1:** According to the comment of Andreas Cap I revise the integral formula in the question.

**Edit 2:** I understand from the following post that some part of the previos version of my question has negative answer, so I completely revise the question:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1506133/is-there-an-odd-continuous-map-fs2-to-gl2-mathbbc

Let  a compact  topological group  $G$  with invariant  measure $\mu,$ acts on  $S^{2}$ and $\rho$ is  a  $n$-dimensional unitary irreducible   representation of $G$. Let $f:S^{2}\to  M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ be  a  continuous  function.  is it true to say that:

> There  exist $x_{0}\in S^{2}$  such that the  following integral is  non invertible:

$$ \int_{G}  \rho(g)f(g^{-1}.x_{0})d\mu  $$

As another question we ask: Is the following statement, true?

> Assume that $\phi$ is  a order $n$  homeomorphism on $S^{4}$ and $\lambda \neq 1$ is  a  quaternion with $\lambda^{n}=1$.Assume that $f:S^{4}\to \mathbb{R}^{4} \simeq \mathbb{H}$ is  a  continuous function. Then there is  a point $x_{0}\in S^{4}$  such that $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \lambda^{n-i}f(\phi^{i}(x_{0}))=0$.

Note that the particular case $\lambda=-1$  and $\phi=$ The antipodal map is the classical Borsuk-Ulam theorem.

The motivation for the first question is that the statement is true for $1$ dimensional representation.

The motivation for the last part of the question is that the above statement is true if we replace $S^{4}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{4}$  by $S^{2}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{2}\simeq \mathbb{C}$, respectively  and choose $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Algebraic topology?

Comment: @FernandoMuro  yes because the  (algebraic) topological property of $X$ is essential in this  question.9In fact $X$ is  simply  connected or  with finite  $\pi_{1}$

Comment: The fact that the fundamental group shows up doesn't make the question an algebraic topology one.

Comment: @FernandoMuro If you are sure, so i delete the tag. but the  covering lifting lemma in algebraic topology  is very essential here!

Comment: It's just an opinion, I'm not sure about anything.

Comment: @FernandoMuro Thanks  for the comment. i deleted  the tag:)

Comment: @paulgarrett  Prof. Garrett  Thank you very much  for the comment. I apologize if my question is trivial: Could you please explain that Why for translation action, the integral under my question is the fourrier transform? Morover, as I asked in my question, what about compact $G$  and $X$?

Comment: @FernandoMuro Is $e^{A}:M_{n}(\mathbb{C})\to GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ a  covering  space?

Comment: @AliTaghavi No, the complex general linear group has higher homotopy groups, so it cannot have a contractible covering space.

Comment: @paulgarrett thank  you  for  your  comment. the  answer to my question is affirmative  for  $G$  abelian, since the only irreducible representation is one  dim.

Comment: @paulgarrett  I  forgot to  add the  assumption "X  is  Compact"  Now I edited the  question. So in this  case,  for  G  abelian the  answer is  affirmative.

Comment: Ah, ok, in light of your edits, I'll remove my earlier comments in a little while...

Comment: I don't quite understand the motivation for looking at that integral. If you would put $\int_G\rho(g)f(g^{-1}x)$ then there is a simple interpretation:  This would mean that you view $f$ as a function $X\to V^n$, where $V$ is the space on which $G$ is represented and average for the natural action of $G$ on the space of such maps. Thus the result would be $G$-equivariant for that action. One would get an analogous statement for the natural action on maps $X\to L(V,V)$ when  considering $\int_G\rho(g)f(g^{-1}x)\rho(g)^{-1}$.

Comment: @AndreasCap Thank you for your comment. in the first part of your comment, I think you mean $f:X\to V$ rather to $V^{n}$ so the value of integral lies in $V$, so we could not speak about invertieblity. regarding the motivation of such formula, as I said in the question, we are motivated by representation of cyclic groups of order n on $\mathbb{C}$(when we choose a nth root of unity) and a continuous map $f:X \to C$ is  counted as a map to $M_{1}(C)$. the motivation comes from proposition 3 of this note:http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.0091 But you replace g by g^{-1}. I think for G abelian the result

Comment: ..is  almost the same. but I do not know for non abelian. The advantage of your consideration is that it is the usual" average"

Comment: in fact the main motivation of this question is a possible generalization of the Borsuk Ulam Theorem

Comment: I mean $V^n$ and not $V$, and the analog of invertibility is that all values consist of linearly independent vectors. For the other part, the question is whether you can interpret the statement as the value at $x$ of $\int_G g\cdot f$ for some action on $G$ on a space of functions or not. (I don't claim that such an interpretation would readily answer your question, but it provides a way how to think about the quesiton.) Concerning motivation, I rather mean motivation why the claimed property should hold, rather than what it could be used for.

Comment: @AndreasCap  Now  I understand the advantage of your formulation: the action of $G$ on the function under integral(integrad) is: $h.F=\rho(h) F$ but with my formulation it is not the case. So i revise the question. Thanks for your interesting comment.